# Hints in a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the next vectors on $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$ U = \begin{pmatrix}1 & k & 5\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{10pt} V = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -3 & 2\end{pmatrix},\hspace{10pt} W = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

An I was asked to find $k$ in order to make  $U$ a linear combination of $V$, $W$

Please some hints...

Comment: Do you know the definition of a linear combination?

Comment: A sum of the elements from some set with constant coefficients placed in front of each. For example, a linear combination of the vectors x, y, and z is given by
 ax+by+cz, 
where a, b, and c are constants.

My guess is that k=-4 using an scalar 3n as common denominator of the 3 vectors. Am I right?

Comment: Right, so what is definition of $U$ being a linear combination of $V,W$?

Comment: 3{1, -4, 5}==3{1, -3, 2}+3{2, -1, 1}?

Comment: Mi question was because it not seams the same to say the former is equal to the original statement.  Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the easy

**Lemma:**  If $\;v_1\,,\,v_2\in V\;$ are two linearly independent vectors in a linear space, then a third vector $\;w\in W\;$ is a linear combination of $\;v_1\,,\,v_2\;$ iff $\;\{v_1,v_2,w\}\;$ is a linearly *dependent* set.

Check (by reducing it, say) thus the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&2\\2&-1&1\\1&\;\;k&5\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&\;\;2\\0&\;\;5&-3\\0&k+3&\;\;3\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\;\ldots$$

So, what has to happen in order to get in the next step a row of all-zeros in the last row?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the definitions: If $U$ is a linear combination of $V$ and $W$, then
\begin{align*}
(1,k,5) = U = aV + bW = a(1, -3, 2) + b(2, -1, 1) = (a + 2b, -3a - b, 2a + b)
\end{align*}
for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.  The first and third entries give you two equations in two unknowns: can you solve for $a$ and $b$?